# General JavaScript Doubts

Tags: javascript, c++, variables

In C++ I have learned that Variables are the used for Data Storage and Objects are the instance of a Class. But in JavaScript I have seen people referring variables as an Object. Why are the Variables referred as Objects in JavaScript.  I am getting confused with that.

Comment: Can you put a code example of what you're talking about in your question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In javascript, a variable can either hold a single piece of data itself (like the number `3` or a text string like `"Having Fun"`) or it can hold a reference to an entity like an array or an object.

An object in javascript is essentially a container in javascript.  It can hold multiple properties that are each accessed with a key.  For example, an object could have a property named "name" that contains the value "Bob", it could also contain a property named "Age" with a value of `29`.  Objects can have as many properties as one wants.  As such objects are essentially a collection of multiple variables, where each variable has its own name and value.

There are technically no "classes" in javascript so it doesn't work the same way that C++ does.  Javascript uses prototypes and objects instead of classes and instances in C++.

In reference to the specifics of your question, a variable can contain a value or a reference to an object.  There is no right or wrong, it depends upon the problem to be solved.

Some examples:

```
var person = {};      // a variable `person` that contains a reference to an empty object
person.name = "Bob";  // add a property "name" and value to the object
person.age = 29;      // add a property "age" and value to the object

var numPeople = 12;   // a variable that just contains a number
```

Comment: In the following code, is it correct to say that Variable formInThePage is an Object and var Cool is a Variable that stores integer value.`var formOnThePage = {
    method: 'post',
    action: 'form.php',
    write: tellMeStuff
};var Cool = 2;`

Comment: @sandbox - I think you're arguing some semantics here.  I would call both `formOnThePage` and `Cool` variables.  `formOnThePage` contains a reference to an object.  `Cool` contains a simple numeric value.  The reason I would call `formOnThePage` a variable is that it can be assigned a different value like this `formOnThePage = [1,2,3];` or `formOnThePage = "fun";`.  It wasn't the object itself, just a variable that contained a reference to the object.

Comment: a variable is a container. an object is essentially a container also (of more variables). classes are used as objects. therefore, variables can be objects which can also be classes. *prototype-based programming is seen as encouraging the programmer to focus on the behavior of some set of examples and only later worry about classifying these objects* - which means they are all containers of data no matter what they're called :) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based

Answer (score 1):

[Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript) is [prototype based](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prototype-based) OOP language.

> Prototype-based programming is a style of object-oriented programming
>   in which classes **are not present**, and behavior reuse (known as
>   inheritance in class-based languages) is performed via a process of
>   cloning existing objects that serve as prototypes.

Answer (score -1):

In Javascript we use DOcument Object Model(DOM) for refering to different elements of web page.
so when we refer to window,document,form they all are objects and variables are declared like
var x=0;
following will be example of object assignment.
var w=window;

Comment: Then wat is foo called here, object or variable: `var foo = {name: "foo", one: 1, two: 2};`

Comment: what i was trying to simply differentiate in short why we refers most of the things as object rather plain variable in c++.